# Digital Ocean Ubuntu 18.0.x ssh user@ip_address refused (publickey), now Github Doesn't recognize my computer. What's up? Should I be worried?

Tags: server, ssh, vpn, firewall, cloud

I'm using a Digital Ocean Ubuntu 18.0.x instance and connecting from my Ubuntu machine and my Mac. when I `ssh user@ip_address` I get the message summarized to this will be added to `authorized_keys` (or known_hosts) but refusing connection unknown server (publickey), now Github Doesn't recognize my computer. What's up?

I've been using ExpressVPN until yesterday. Now i'm having all these issues, could they be related, and should I be worried that there is someone at the other end of this trying to MinM me. What steps can I take to verify my ssh keys on my local and on my server/github like a checksum or the face key symbol, anything? Sorry if i'm botching terminology I hope you understand what i'm asking.

Could this be ufw or the settings? I've enabled tcp ssh connections, anything else? Port forwarding? What should I look for to rule out vulnerability and can I verify it, and if so how?

Should I be worried? I thought the digital ocean thing was annoying and weird, and I still cant figure out how to ssh into one of my ubuntu droplets from my linux machine.  What if I get the same request from another terminal (mac or windows) that i've used in the past? Should I be worried then, and what should I do if so to counter this or "seal up" some of my vulnerability.

Or is this just a case of needing to copy ssh keys to known_hosts? it's a pain because it wont let me copy it, it pastes a different ssh key when I try, i'd have to type it out manually through the ubuntu recovery console in digital oceans dashboard. Any clue what that's about? It contained '('s and '<'s '>'s then some other characters within the key, is this a protection mechanism? I tried `ssh-key-copy` or whatever allows you to normally copy over your ssh key to useryour@website_ip. I may have typed that copy command wrong incorrect here but I tried the correct one, i'm just going off my memory right now. Any input would be greatly appreciated by any Ubuntu wizards. I'm a bit of a rook, I've been running basic ubuntu for a few years for development and the great ease of use when programming in laravel in the bash terminal, I love it. It's cut down but full featured and USB-ready when needed (i.e. tails) but i'm not a superuser like I am with Windows or Mac.

Comment: whatever SSH keys you've got on your system aren't being sent across to your DO node, or are being sent but your DO node isn't accepting them (meaning you never copied them right).  However you're specifying two separate issues - GitHub, and DO.  It's also `authorized_keys`, not `known_hosts`, for specifying public SSH keys that are authorized to SSH into a user on a remote machine

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, I knew that. I just was in that directory. I'll correct that. So I need to copy my id_rsa.pub into authorized_hosts cut/paste save quit?

Comment: Typically, yes, for your DO node.  For GitHub you need to add your SSH keys to the GitHub authorized SSH keys page from the web browser, there is no 'copy id' function

Comment: Okay, maybe I regen'd my ssh key and don't remember it. That's odd. It works on one of my nodes, doesn't work on 3 must have been added after a change that I don't recall I guess. Any idea why I cant copy and paste from bash into DO console? It seems to let me copy anything else, passwords, scripts, functions, etc. Just not all of the ssh key and what part it does copy isn't the same thing. Its bizarre. Also known_hosts is a part of this somehow, it mentions adding this device as it doesn't recognize it, therefore I add my ssh key to authorized_keys but anything required of me for known_hosts?